# How can I use a different separators in join() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

E.g., given a list `nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` I want to join each pair by a semicolon and each number within that pair by a comma to receive the following string: `result = 1,2;3,4;5,6;7,8`.

How can I do it without `for` loop (e.g., using a `join`)?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `slicing`

**Ex:**

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
nums = [str(i) for i in nums]
print( ";".join(",".join(nums[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(nums), 2)) )
```

**Output:**

```
1,2;3,4;5,6;7,8
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also [cycle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) through the separators:

```
from itertools import cycle, chain

nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
nums = [str(n) for n in nums]

''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip(nums, cycle(',;'))))[:-1]
# '1,2;3,4;5,6;7,8'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
result = ";".join([",".join([str(i) for i in nums[k:k+2] ]) for k in range(len(nums)-2)])
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
'1,2;2,3;3,4;4,5;5,6;6,7'
```